# Error with xlrd and open_woorkbook

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

I´m starting programming with python and I keep receiving the same error in this program:

```
import xlrd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt

file_location = " X:\ \blabla.xlsx"

import workbook
wb=xlrd.open_workbook(filename= 'blabla.xlsx')
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in
>
> **AttributeError: module 'xlrd' has no attribute 'open_workbook'**

The paths are well written and I don´t have more than one xlrd module, which I looked up trough help function:

```
help(xlrd)
```

> Help on package xlrd:
>
> NAME
>       xlrd
>
> PACKAGE CONTENTS FILE
>       (built-in)

Comment: When you run the exact code you pasted here, what is the full text of the traceback?

Comment: Bear in mind that your file_location isn't a valid windows path/file because it includes odd spaces

Comment: The full text of the Traceback is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'xlrd' has no attribute 'open_workbook'
>>>

The path is a valid windows pathfile. I obtain it from the properties of the file. The wanted file is in the X hard disk stored

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem when I named a test python file as xlrd.py which is the same name as the module. I changed the name of my file and it worked.

Comment: This was the exact issue I had. Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, which was, as I figured out, due to the linux permissions. Running pip3 as root, the installer made the contents of the package only visible for the root user. Strangely, the command

```
import xlrd
```

did not report any error, just nothing has been imported. The shell commands

```
sudo chmod -R go+r /usr/local/lib
sudo find /usr/local/lib -type d -execdir chmod go+x {} +
```

solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

> AttributeError: module 'xlrd' has no attribute 'open_workbook'

It means that `open_workbook` was **not** recognized as a *method* (i. e. a *function*) - what you wanted - but as an *attribute* (i. e. an *variable*).

Methods have opening parenthesis `(` after them while attributes don't.

So something is bad - your real code is probably different from the code in your question, because in your question you *have* `(` after the name `open_workbook`.

Comment: It´s the same code. I swear. That´s why I don´t get this error

Comment: Important are only **2 last lines** of your code (and they are independent of the previous code). They work perfectly for me. Try them one by one in your interpreter, but **NOT** with copy/paste - type them **manually**. If they will work, copy/paste them back to your code and your code will work, too.

Comment: I typed them manually and still getting the same error. It´s the last line, which gives me troubles.  I also tried this: from xlrd import open_workbook, with the same result. But if I write from xlrd import * there isn´t any error. I don´t understand anything

Comment: Agreed, there's nothing wrong with this code, `xlrd.open_workbook(path_to_file)` should be valid syntax

Comment: @Albamfc if you get an error with `from xlrd import open_workbook` then there's something wrong with your xlrd package.

Comment: ok. Then I´ll try to uninstall and install it again and see if it works

Comment: Now it runs. I´ve installed it again with the easy_install-3.6 script and it´s running. @David Zemens, you were right

Comment: This answer is wrong. An [AttributeError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html?highlight=attributeerror#AttributeError) is raised when the given name is not found in the expected place. In this case it means that `open_workbook` was not found in `xlrd`. Whether the missing item should have been "a method" or "a variable", whether parentheses are used or not, is irrelevant.