# python xlrd attribute error

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

Im trying to view basic info in an excel file ,like sheet names,etc

```
from xlrd import open_workbook
book = open_workbook('SampleData.xlsx')
book.sheet_names
```

However it dosent seem to recognize sheetname, sheet_by_index etc .Below is the error

```
AttributeError: module 'xlrd.book' has no attribute 'sheet_names'
```

Comment: It means that `xlrd` has no attribute named `sheet_names`. It's a function and it needs parentheses `sheet_names()`. Read the docs at https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error with xlrd and open\_woorkbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43070508/error-with-xlrd-and-open-woorkbook)

Answer (score -1):

After reading the documentation [Here](https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), I found out that a line in your code is calling a function but it is missing parantheses. That function being `sheet_names()`. Just change the following in your code for it to work...

```
from xlrd import open_workbook
book = open_workbook('SampleData.xlsx')
book.sheet_names()  #ADD THE MISSING PARANTHESES HERE
```

Hope it helps. Happy coding :)