# AttributeError: module 'xlrd' has no attribute 'open_workbook'

Tags: python, attributeerror, xlrd

I am trying to process Excel 97 .XLS file using `xlrd` library in Python. My code looks like this

```
import xlrd

def load_xls():
   with xlrd.open_workbook('abc.xls') as wb:       
     for row in range(wb.nrows):
        for col in range(wb.ncols):
           cellValue = wb.cell_value(row, col)
           print (cellValue)
```

The code results in

```
AttributeError: module 'xlrd' has no attribute 'open_workbook'
```

My `xlrd` version is 2.0.1

Comment: Check if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43070508) is relevant to your issue

Comment: Why would it work to change it to `.xlsx` when its an `.xls` file? I'm not saying it won't - just curious?

Comment: According to this Excel 97 files have `.xls` extension https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/file-formats-that-are-supported-in-excel-0943ff2c-6014-4e8d-aaea-b83d51d46247

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error with xlrd and open\_woorkbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43070508/error-with-xlrd-and-open-woorkbook)

Answer (score 0):

Based on various comments posted, I did use an interpreter to perform the following commands

```
import xlrd
dir(xlrd)
```

This displayed the functions available within xlrd, which led me to find out that it was referring to a local file which, I had named xlrd.py

Renamed the file with another name and it resolved the issues - basically it was referring to a local file instead of xlrd lib installed